# Ms access get row number from a subquery not table

Tags: sql, ms-access, numbers, subquery, row

I have the following Ms Access query that retrieves data successfully:

```
SELECT stockInventory.purchaseId, stockInventory.itemId, item.itemName, stockInventory.unitId, unit.unitDesc, stockInventory.quantity, stockInventory.costPrice
FROM unit INNER JOIN (item INNER JOIN stockInventory ON item.itemId = stockInventory.itemId) ON unit.unitId = stockInventory.unitId
WHERE (((stockInventory.purchaseId)=1))
```

Now I want to retrieve these data with row number!

I tried the following:

```
SELECT A.*, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.itemId>=itemId ) as rowNo
FROM 
(
SELECT stockInventory.purchaseId, stockInventory.itemId, item.itemName, stockInventory.unitId, unit.unitDesc, stockInventory.quantity, stockInventory.costPrice
FROM unit INNER JOIN (item INNER JOIN stockInventory ON item.itemId = stockInventory.itemId) ON unit.unitId = stockInventory.unitId
WHERE (((stockInventory.purchaseId)=1))
)  AS A;
```

But it says: The Microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'A' as the following picture:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you supply a query that does the counting as well? Then it would be easier to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: This query get the total records:    SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
SELECT stockInventory.purchaseId, stockInventory.itemId, item.itemName, stockInventory.unitId, unit.unitDesc, stockInventory.quantity, stockInventory.costPrice
FROM unit INNER JOIN (item INNER JOIN stockInventory ON item.itemId = stockInventory.itemId) ON unit.unitId = stockInventory.unitId
WHERE (((stockInventory.purchaseId)=1))
)  AS A;

Answer (score 1):

The additional SELECT part

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.itemId>=itemId ) as rowNo
```

is a separate query that doesn't know about `A`.

I think you must save your original query (= the subquery) as new named query, then you can reference it in both SELECT parts.

```
SELECT A.*, 
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mySubquery AS B WHERE B.itemId>=A.itemId ) as rowNo
FROM mySubquery AS A
```

Now it also gets clearer that you need two instances of the subquery (A and B).

I hope you don't have too many records, because performance will probably be bad. But that wasn't the focus here...

Answer (score 0):

Consider directly adding `rowNo` subquery in original query:

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*) FROM stockInventory AS sub 
        WHERE sub.itemId <= stockInventory.itemId) AS rowNo, 
        stockInventory.purchaseId, stockInventory.itemId, item.itemName, 
        stockInventory.unitId, unit.unitDesc, stockInventory.quantity, 
        stockInventory.costPrice 
FROM unit 
INNER JOIN (item 
INNER JOIN stockInventory 
ON item.itemId = stockInventory.itemId) 
ON unit.unitId = stockInventory.unitId 
WHERE (((stockInventory.purchaseId)=1))
```